# Is there any way to read the .xlsx extension file in .net core 3.1?

Tags: excel, backend, xlsx, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I have front end created in Angular 10 and backend is in .net core 3.1

Requirement: Upload file(.xlsx) from front end which will be parsed in web api and extracted data will be stored in SQL Server.

Using below code to upload the file from Angular

```
const formData = new FormData();
    
 for (const file of fileToUpload) {
     formData.append(file.name, file);
 }
```

I'm getting file in format of IFormFileCollection in web api.

I am unable to read the file content in web api.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please show what you have tried and why you are `unable to read the file content in web api`? Also, include what library are you using to read the excel file.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal Somehow now am able to read it, Thanks for your immediate reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
      IFormFile postedFile = file[0];
      string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
      string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
      using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
      {
           postedFile.CopyTo(stream);
      }
      string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
      using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
      {
            connection.Open();
            if (workBook != string.Empty)
            {
                 //To apply query on the worksheet we need to apply '$' sign after worksheet name
                 workBook = workBook + "$";
                 //Select all records from worksheet table                        
                 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [" + workBook + "]", connection);

                 //Execute the reader
                 using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         //Create table
                         sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                         sqlConn.Open();
                         cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = sqlConn };

                         // Bulk Copy to created table
                         using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connString))
                         {
                                   bulkCopyData.DestinationTableName = TABLE_NAME;
                                    bulkCopyData.WriteToServer(dr);
                         }
                    }
              }
       }
```